# Perfmon show Process CPU usage

Tags: perfmon

I would like to show one process CPUs usage with Perfmon.

I already know how it should work.

In your collection you can select your indicators and you select "Add.."

Then you select Process and below you can select your instances like explorer.exe etc.

Now I have just explorer.exe in my list and start my collection.

If I finish the collection and view the results I see in my chart Object "process" --> OK but in column "instance" I read _Total and not my selected process --> NOK

How can I show juste one process in my chart and why does it not work lije I am trying it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the 'Add >>' button. This will add that counter in added counter list on the right side. Now select "OK".. It should work.